# Why can't download image on android captive portal browser?

Tags: android, mobile, browser, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I have made image coupon download service using captive portal browser.
So, I made coupon download page using download html5 tag.

```
<a href="src" download>download img</a>
```

This works well on PC but, doesn't work on mobile.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this question is about a specific piece of code you have written. Please edit your question to include the code as it is, so people can find the problem.